# Css and Js file does not load

Tags: magento-1.9

My custom css and Js file does not load.

I call it in page.xml file. I want to load it in home page and footer but it does not load. Check for reference site

http://meusoculos.online/

Comment: add your code too.

Comment: <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owl.carousel.min.css</stylesheet></action>

Comment: check please above my code

Answer (score 0):

Now try this.

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addCss">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <stylesheet>owl.carousel.min.css</stylesheet>
  </action>
</reference>
```

**just for example**

```
 <reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem">
         <type>skin_css</type><name>slider/css/owl.carousel.css</name><params/>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: which file i add this code

Comment: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: i create custom theme there is not local.xml file in my theme

Comment: You can create theme.xml in your theme also

Comment: create local.xml file in your theme

Comment: http://www.techawaken.com/add-js-css-file-home-page-magento/ try this